# Push capabilities doesn't warn user, and nothing in Capabilities

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm working on some older code trying to debug push.

I have a signed push cert/key in my keychain. I exported to PEMs and could log onto Apple's test site. When I run the app, it appears in Settings->Notifications with Badges turned on, as I expect.

However, when you launch the app for the first time, the user is not asked if they want to allow push. This *may* because there is another alert for map access?

Also, when I go to the Xcode Capabilities tab, Push does not even appear in the list. Is it supposed to?

I have a sinking feeling someone missed a step - probably me. Is there somewhere inside Xcode I can look to see if I've imported the certs and such properly?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that push is never presented in Xcode Capabilities tab.

If you don't see the notification request, try reset your test device, next time you run your app, the alert should show, since there is a minimum time limit for the push privilege request, reinstall app without reset device won't do.

Comment: I'm running on the iPhone itself, deleting/reinstalling each time. Does that change anything?

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz if it is OK, try reset your device, make sure you back up your data. Simulator won't receive push, I'm updating my answer.